# Как разделить записи постранично, wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, cms

Предположим, что у меня есть три страницы блога, нужно сделать так, чтобы на каждой странице блога можно было выводить разные посты. Т.е. я хочу добавлять на каждую страницу отдельные посты со своим содержимым.

Вот как это выглядит, посты разные, их надо как-то разграничивать постранично.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первое что приходит в голову - создавать отдельную рубрику для каждой страницы, но это же бред.

Какие варианты есть для реализации?

Comment: А что не бред? Вам все равно придется какой-то идентификатор, метку, тег вешать на пост, чтобы понять - на какой странице его выводить

Comment: Дело в том, что заказчик сам создает страницы, вряд ли он будет лезть в код и менять там название рубрики

Comment: Первое, что нужно сделать - это разобраться с сущностями ВП и тогда всё станет на свои места. См https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE/#post-155549 И да. Забыть о страницах и писать *записи* в *рубрики*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не в ту сторону мыслите. Изучите цикл WP_Query(), и вопрос сам по себе отпадет.
Вот [статья](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query) с, наверное, самым подробным русским описанием.